# How to use wsgen tool for SOAP/JMS Web Services

Tags: web-services, websphere, ibm-rad

I am following the tutorial [[here]](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/tutorials/0903_adams/#03) to create a Web Services application in RAD. However, when I try to add a new function in EchoSOAPImpl.java:

```
@WebMethod
public String getInput(String input) {
    return "Your input is: " + input;
}
```

and then use wsgen to generate the necessary java files:

```
wsgen -s ejbModule -cp build\classes -d build com.ibm.was.wssample.sei.echo.EchoSOAPImpl
```

, it failed with this error message:

```
error: Could not create declaration for annotation type javax.ejb.Stateless
```

I tried to delete the annotation, but the whole project shows the error:

```
An EJB module must contain one or more enterprise beans.m
```

I am so frustrated with building Web Services in RAD. There are very few tutorials or study materials provided. Please also provide any other useful materials about Web Service in RAD.

EchoSOAPImpl.java

```
package com.ibm.was.wssample.sei.echo;

@javax.ejb.Stateless
@javax.jws.WebService(endpointInterface = "com.ibm.was.wssample.sei.echo.EchoServicePortType", targetNamespace = "http://com/ibm/was/wssample/sei/echo/", serviceName = "EchoService", portName = "EchoServicePort")
public class EchoSOAPImpl implements EchoServicePortType {

@Override
public EchoStringResponse echoOperation(EchoStringInput parameter) {
    ...
    return response;
}

@Override
public String getInput(String input) {
    return "Your input is: " + input;
}
```

}

EchoServicePortType

```
@WebService(name = "EchoServicePortType", targetNamespace = "http://com/ibm/was/wssample/sei/echo/")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso( { ObjectFactory.class })
public interface EchoServicePortType {

@WebMethod(action = "echoOperation")
@WebResult(name = "echoStringResponse", targetNamespace = "http://com/ibm/was/wssample/sei/echo/", partName = "parameter")
public EchoStringResponse echoOperation(
        @WebParam(name = "echoStringInput", targetNamespace = "http://com/ibm/was/wssample/sei/echo/", partName = "parameter") EchoStringInput parameter);

@WebMethod(action = "getInput")
@WebResult(name = "getInputResponse", targetNamespace = "http://com/ibm/was/wssample/sei/echo/", partName = "parameter")
public String getInput(@WebParam(name = "getInputInput", targetNamespace = "http://com/ibm/was/wssample/sei/echo/", partName = "parameter") String getInput);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `wsgen`. I suggest that you add the IBM EJB API jar that contains @Stateless in the `wsgen` classpath such as:

```
wsgen -s ejbModule -cp {ibm javaeJB jar}:build\classes -d build com.ibm.was.wssample.sei.echo.EchoSOAPImpl
```

That is assuming that as you are using RAD that you are using Websphere also. If not add the standard Java EE jar.

Comment: I used the following command now:
wsgen -s ejbModule -cp "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\plugins\javax.j2ee.ejb.jar;build\classes" -d build com.ibm.was.wssample.sei.echo.EchoSOAPImpl
This time, no error occurred but also no classes are generated. I have modified slightly for the EchoSOAPImpl class, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Java EE API jar to the classpath like here:
`wsgen -wsdl -cp  .;javaee-api-6.0.jar com.vvirlan.MyWsEjb`